# Bind store size to table's header

Tags: extjs

I have ExtJS application and I want to implement displaying total number of records in the header.
[image]

ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
// ...

    stores: {
        users: Ext.create("AppName.store.UsersStore")
    }
});
```

Binding to view

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.main.UsersPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  // ...
    items:[{
        bind : {
           title : 'Users ({users.data.length})'
        },
        items: [{
            listeners : {
               cellclick : 'OnSelectUser'
           },
           xtype: 'grid', columns: [
                { text: 'Full Name', dataIndex: 'fullName', flex: 2},
                { text: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address', flex: 1},
                { text: 'Sex', dataIndex: 'sex', flex: 1},
                { text: 'Date Of Birth', dataIndex: 'dob', flex: 1}
            ],
            bind: '{users}'
        }]
    }]
});
```

And this works after first loading of records to Store by code

```
OnSearchButtonClick: function () {
    var me = this,
        usersStore = me.getViewModel().get('users');
    usersStore.load();
}
```

But when I remove records from store by code

```
   var me = this,
       usersStore = me.getViewModel().get('users');
   usersStore.loadData([], false);
```

or by

```
   usersStore.removeAll()
```

then only table is cleared but not header.

So I have a question: how can I bind store size?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with sync on the store after removing records.

```
usersStore.removeAll();
usersStore.sync();
```

sometimes binding not refresh binded components because new or removed records are not synched in the store

Comment: Have you tryed to refresh also the container?